# strings in file do not match to string in a set

Tags: python, string, set, comparison, equals

I have a file with a word in each line and a set with words, and I want to put not equal words from set called 'out' to the file. There is part of my code:

```
def createNextU(self):
    print "adding words to final file"
    if not os.path.exists(self.finalFile):
        open(self.finalFile, 'a').close
    fin = open(self.finalFile,"r")
    out = set()
    for line in self.lines_seen: #lines_seen is a set with words
        if line not in fin:
            out.add(line)
        else:
            print line
    fin.close()
    fout= open(self.finalFile,"a+")
    for line in out:
        fout.write(line)
```

but it only match a bit of real equal words. I play with the same dictionary of words and it add repeat words to file each run. What I am doing wrong?? what happening?? I try to use '==' and 'is' comparators and I have the same result.

Edit 1: I am working with huge files(finalFile), which can't be full loaded at RAM, so I think I should read file line by line

Edit 2: Found big problem with pointer:

```
def createNextU(self):
    print "adding words to final file"
    if not os.path.exists(self.finalFile):
        open(self.finalFile, 'a').close
    out = set()
    out.clear()
    with open(self.finalFile,"r") as fin:
        for word in self.lines_seen:
            fin.seek(0, 0)'''with this line speed down to 40 lines/second,without it dont work'''
            if word in fin:
                self.totalmatches = self.totalmatches+1
            else:
                out.add(word)
                self.totalLines=self.totalLines+1


    fout= open(self.finalFile,"a+")
    for line in out:
        fout.write(line)
```

If I put the lines_seen bucle before opening the file, I open the file for each line in lines_seen, but speed ups to 30k lines/second only. With set() I am having 200k lines/second at worst, so I think I will load the file by parts and compare it using sets. Any better solution?

Edit 3: Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fin` is a filehandle so you can't compare it with `if line not in fin`. The content needs to be read first.

```
with open(self.finalFile, "r") as fh:
    fin = fh.read().splitlines()   # fin is now a list of words from finalFile

for line in self.lines_seen: #lines_seen is a set with words
    if line not in fin:
        out.add(line)
    else:
        print line
# remove fin.close()
```

EDIT:

Since `lines_seen` is a set, try to create a new set with the words from `finalFile` then diff the sets?

```
file_set = set()

with open(self.finalFile, "r") as fh:
    for f_line in fh:
        new_set.add(f_line.strip())

# This will give you all the words in finalFile that are not in lines_seen.
print new_set.difference(self.lines_seen)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this and something was wrong, console output get freezed, idk why, but thanks a lot!!

Comment: Hi @user3754301 maybe try to create a new set with `finalFile` and diff that with your word set.

Comment: I load the file by small parts into sets which RAM can hold I and use 'difference' some times to finally get unique words. With this solution I get very hight performance. thnx!!

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison is likely not working because the lines read from the file will have a newline at the end, so you are comparing 'word\n' to 'word'. Using 'rstrip' will help remove the trailing newlines:

```
>>> foo = 'hello\n'
>>> foo
'hello\n'
>>> foo.rstrip()
'hello'
```

I would also iterate over the file, rather than iterate over the variable containing the words you would like to check against. If I've understood your code, you would like to write anything that is in self.lines_seen to self.finalFile, if it is not already in it. If you use 'if line not in fin' as you have, this will not work as you're expecting. For example, if your file contains:

```
lineone
linetwo
linethree
```

and the set lines_seen, being unordered, returns 'linethree' and then 'linetwo', then the following will match 'linethree' but not 'linetwo' because the file object has already read past it:

```
with open(self.finalFile,"r" as fin:
    for line in self.lines_seen:
        if line not in fin:
            print line
```

Instead, consider using a counter:

```
from collections import Counter
linecount = Counter()
# using 'with' means you don't have to worry about closing it once the block ends
with open(self.finalFile,"r") as fin:
    for line in fin:
        line = line.rstrip() # remove the right-most whitespace/newline
        linecount[line] += 1
for word in self.lines_seen:
    if word not in linecount:
        out.add(word)
```

Comment: Hi !!, first thanks to all for your answers.
If I have a huge file to open, like 100GB, which can't be loaded at memory(RAM), using this Counter will get a memory error, right?